# Count distinct values document in mongodb

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm trying to count the values of my `blood_group` under the distinct value of `blood_category`, As of my code, I can only output the overall total sum of `num_stock` under the distinct value of `blood_category`. How can I store the count in a single array? Here is a sample document:

> ```
> blood_category:"platelet"
> blood_group:"A",
> num_stock:10
>
> blood_category:"platelet"
> blood_group:"B",
> num_stock:10
>
> blood_category:"whole blood"
> blood_group:"A",
> num_stock:20
>
> blood_category:"whole blood"
> blood_group:"B",
> num_stock:20
> ```

**I'm expecting an output like this:**

```
{_id: "platelets", A:10, B:10},
{_id: "whole blood", A:20, B:20},
```

**What I tried, Code:**

```
Bloodinventory.aggregate([{$group: {_id : "$blood_category" , count :{$sum:"$num_stock"}}},{$sort: {_id: 1}}],function(err, inventory) {     
     res.json({ success: true, inventory: inventory });
});
```

**Using the above sample, my code yields to:**

```
{_id: "platelets", count:20},
{_id: "whole blood", count:40},
```

Comment: It think its not a duplicate, as the value depends on given field

Comment: `Bloodinventory.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {  
            "c": "$blood_category",  
            "g": "$blood_group" 
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.c",
        "counts": {
            "$push": {
                "k": "$_id.g",
                "v": "$count"
            }
        }
    } },
    {  "$project": {
         "data": {"$mergeObjects": ["$$ROOT", { "$arrayToObject": "$counts" } ] }
    }  },
    { 
        "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": "$data"
        } 
    }
])`

Comment: wow thanks sir, solved my problem

Comment: Typo in my code above, the count in the first `$group` pipeline should be `count: { "$sum": "$num_stock" }`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to get your desired output with your current document structure. However, I was able to do it with a modified document structure which may help you.

This is your current document structure:

```
db.blood.insertMany([
   { category: "platelet", group: "A", num_stock: 10 },
   { category: "platelet", group: "B", num_stock: 10 },
   { category: "whole blood", group: "A", num_stock: 20 },
   { category: "whole blood", group: "B", num_stock: 20 }
]);
```

This is the modified document structure:

```
db.blood.insertMany([
   { category: "platelet", stock: { "A": 10 }},
   { category: "platelet", stock: { "B": 10 }},
   { category: "whole blood", stock: { "A": 20 }},
   { category: "whole blood", stock: { "B": 20 }}
]);
```

Using the modified document structure, it is possible to use the [Aggregation Pipeline Operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/):

```
db.blood.aggregate( [
   { $group: { _id: "$category", mergedCategories: { $mergeObjects: "$stock" } } }
])
```

Which gives:

```
{ "_id" : "whole_blood", "mergedCategories" : { "A" : 20, "B" : 20 } }
{ "_id" : "platelet", "mergedCategories" : { "A" : 10, "B" : 10 } }
```

For a solution that uses your current document structure, I would look into the examples provided in [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/).